# How to show selected items of certain table on the different table in Dynamics AX 2012?

Tags: x++, microsoft-dynamics, ax

So, I have two tables InventTable (for inverntory) and MyCartTable. I want to connect this tables so when I chose some item or items in InventTable to show in MyCartTable's grid. MyCartTable fields are ItemNumber, ProductName, PartyID;

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are working with AX 2012: 
On your MyCartTable, remove the itemNumber field.
Open an other AOT windows go to Data Dictionary - Extended Data Types and locate the itemId data type. Drag and drop this data type on your table. AX will ask if you want to add a foreign key relation. **Click yes**, this will add a relation to the InventTable to the relations node of your table. 
Now on your form, set the JoinSource property of your MyCartTable to you inventTable data source.

If you are having trouble making this work, create a new form with only those two datasources and a minimum amount of controls (like just 2 grids), this allows you to test this more easily.

Comment: Hello Klass, thanks for answer. I tried this but do not work :(

Comment: What is the result you are getting? Is the data not shown? or is it not filtered? Mind that because you deleted the itemNumber field and added the itemId, that itemId will now be empty. Also try to re-add your data sources to your form, sometimes AX doesn't recognize the change. Be sure to set the datasrouce property on you grid to the correct datasource too afterward (one for ivnentTable and the other MyCartTable)

Comment: Also, are you in the AX client or on the EP?
Do you want to ADD items to MyCartTable of do you want to filter the MyCartTable based on your selection?